# jQueryGantt - No template found for type

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, gantt-chart

All,

I have implemented jQueryGantt () but I get an error message:

> No template found for type 'TASKSEDITHEAD'
>   No template found for type 'GANTBUTTONS'

I have searched on the github site and also support site but I can't find a fix tor this. Anyone has an idea?

Or else: does anyone know a good planning / Gantt plugin for Bootstrap / jQuery?

Comment: Seems to [work here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ELhb4iVrh284qD3ouU0f?p=preview) without any errors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he talks about [this jQueryGantt](https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the templates it looks for are written in the "gantt.html" file. If you are trying to use this library/plugin in a page of your own, you also need to include those templates. The library doesn't load them automatically from the gantt.html file.

What I did is copy the whole div with id="gantEditorTemplates" into a new html file ("templates.html") and then do this in the javascript:

```
var ge = new GanttMaster();
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
        .load('templates.html', function(response, status, xhr) {
    // initialize the gantt only after the templates are loaded
    ge.init($("#myGanttContainer"));
});
```

If you want, you can leave the templates in the gantt.html file and load them like this:

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
        .load('gantt.html #gantEditorTemplates', function(response, status, xhr) {
    //[...]
});
```

as per [jQuery's .load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments).